# Get the selected database value in a dropdown in an Edit form

Tags: php

This is a page in controller where the response is fed back to an ajax call. The intention is to fill a specific span in the view with the dropdown values. That is working perfectly in an insertion form. But now i have the necessity to implement this to an edit form. The **EDIT** form should be filled with the database values pertaining to the particular record.

The code which is in the insertion form is(Working):-

```
function getCategories(){
    require_once '../model/sale.php';
    $obj=new Sale();
    $result=$obj->getCategories();
    $html='<select name="category" id="category" class="cat" onchange="getGradeDetails(this.value)" style="width:169px;"><option></option>';
    while($value=  mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $html.='<option value="'.$value['category_code'].'">'.$value['category_desc'].'</option>';
    }
    $html.='</select>';
    echo $html;
}
```

The code which must be in the editing form is:-

```
<option value="<?php echo $value2['category_code']; ?>" <?php if($val['category_code']==$value2['category_code']){?> selected="selected" <?php }?> >
     <?php echo $value2['category_code'] ?>
</option>
```

The Problem I am having is how do I place this to the above '$html' php variable. I think I am missing some apostrophes. Any suggestions would be greatly helpful..

Comment: really not clear what your issue is

Comment: @charlietfl I have written the following code:-
     $html.='<option  value="'.$value['category_code'].'"'.if($val['category_code']==$value['category_code']){.' selected="selected" '.}.'>'.$value['category_desc'].'</option>';

I don't know what apostrophe I am missing here??